# Return two tags from Rails model method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Procedure model with is_payed method:

```html
  # checks if procedure is payed or not
  def is_payed(request)
    if self.payed
      'Yes'
    else
      return 'No', link_to(image_tag('pay.png'), handle_procedure_payment_requests_path(procedure_id:self.id, request_id: request.id), method: :post, class:'pay-icon')
    end
  end
```

Here i try to return two things:

1) string 'No'

2) link_to tag with image as a link

From view I call that method as follows:

```html
<%= procedure.is_payed(@request) %>
```

But i got an error:

```html
undefined method `image_tag' for #<Procedure:0x007fe3a1707240>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is 'payed'? You meant 'paid', I guess? You have a problem because you can't use view helpers in models.

Answer (score 1):

use `ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag` instead `image_tag`

You have to include helper in your model. There is another way in your model add this method:

```
 def helpers
    ActionController::Base.helpers
  end
```

Then use `helpers.image_tag` in this model. You should be able to use helpers method in your model now.
For better understanding see [railscast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/132-helpers-outside-views)

Answer (score 1):

instead of writing in `model` you can try to move the code into `helper`

```
# checks if procedure is payed or not
  def is_payed(procedure, request)
    if procedure.payed
      'Yes'
    else
      return 'No', link_to(image_tag('pay.png'), handle_procedure_payment_requests_path(procedure_id:procedure.id, request_id: request.id), method: :post, class:'pay-icon')
    end
  end
```

and in view

```
<%= is_payed(procedure, @request)%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this error is, you don't have access to `image_tag` view helper method in your model directly. If you want to use `image_tag` helper method in your model, then you have to replace:

```
image_tag('pay.png')
```

with:

```
ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("pay.png")
```

So, your code snippet becomes:

```
# checks if procedure is payed or not
def is_payed(request)
  if self.payed
    'Yes'
  else
    return 'No', link_to(ActionController::Base.helpers.image_tag("pay.png"), handle_procedure_payment_requests_path(procedure_id:self.id, request_id: request.id), method: :post, class:'pay-icon')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you get this error because when executing `<%= procedure.is_payed(@request) %>` method you are now in context of procedure item. Procedure class has no access to link_to method which comes from views helpers. 
What I would suggest you is just to return from `is_played` function `true` or `false` and then in your `erb` file executed `link_to` method

Answer (score 0):

`image_tag` is a helper, should use it in view only

you should create a new helper, give it a name such as `show_procedure_payed_info`

```
def show_procedure_payed_info(procedure)
  if(procedure.payed)
    "Yes"
  else
    "No"...
  end
end
```

and use it in view

```
<%= show_procedure_payed_info(@procedure)%>
```